# The method setMarkupAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type Header

Tags: javascript, java, css

I'm using this code in the Tomcat server in this its working fine but I have changed tomcat to Wildfly server and I'm getting errors,  i have tried text and itextpdf jar and imports how can I do this code in a different way in Java without any error.
how can i do?

`Header script = new Header(HtmlTags.JAVASCRIPT, ""); script.setMarkupAttribute("src", "../../hisglobal/js/jquery-main.min.js"); document.add(script);`

error:The method setMarkupAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type Header

Answer (score 0):

```
            document.addHeader(HtmlTags.JAVASCRIPT, "function addScript(){\r\n" +
                    "   var script = document.createElement('script');\r\n" + 
                    "   script.type= \"text/javascript\";\r\n" + 
                    "    script.src = '../../hisglobal/js/jquery-main.min.js';\r\n" + 
                    "    document.body.appendChild(script);\r\n""}");


document.setJavaScript_onLoad("addScript();");
```